# MVC: On the fly editor for css, js and cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to make an on the fly editor for Views, css and js on an MVC site?

I just want to have a tree control to select folders/files and then selected file opens up in an editor (.cshtml, js or css ).. If we save changes, the changes goes live!!

Comment: just answered my own question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using codemirror.net as a code editor.

Comment: can you please explain the reason for negative votes ?? Code mirror is working perfectly for me to edit any kind files.